# handler mapping of string to varchar in dapper

Tags: dapper

I found the following code in Dapper:

```
sealed partial class DbString : Dapper.SqlMapper.ICustomQueryParameter
{
    ...

    public void AddParameter(IDbCommand command, string name)
    {
        ...
        var param = command.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = name;
        param.Value = (object)Value ?? DBNull.Value;
        if (Length == -1 && Value != null && Value.Length <= 4000)
        {
            param.Size = 4000;
        }
        else
        {
            param.Size = Length;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Why does it compare the length to 4000?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Query-plan cache.

The following queries are separate and independent:

```
select @foo
```

and

```
select @foo
```

If you are confused, that is because the bit I *didn't* show was the parameter declaration - in the first one it is `nvarchar(12)` and in the second one it is `nvarchar(20)`. What the code is trying to *avoid* is a single query, executed twice - for example once with `hello` (5 characters) and once with `world!` (6 characters) having two separate query-plans; that is much less efficient than allowing both to share a plan, and the number of occasions where this choice would *negatively* impact things is *vanishingly* small.

By standardising the length at some arbitrary value, it allows most common values to use the same query-plan cache. The `4000` is fairly arbitrary (well, actually it was chosen because `nvarchar(4000)` is the maximum size before it starts getting into `max` territory), and it could just as well have been `200`, or whatever you want. The code is working on the basis that *most of the time* values are fairly short, so if there *are* larger values, they will be the exception rather than the rule.

Note that all of this only happens if you haven't set the `Length` explicitly; if you want more control over this, simply *set `.Length` to what you want*. The key properties are:

- `IsAnsi` - switches between unicode/not - the `n` in `[n][var]char(len)`
- `IsFixedLength` - switches between fixed/variable length - the `var` in `[n][var]char(len)`
- `Length` - the `len` in `[n][var]char(len)`
- `Value` - the actual contents

Comment: well, seems like my understanding was totally wrong. but, based on the instructions in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx): `...For strings larger than 4000 characters, explicitly set the SqlDbType.` and your explain, there isn`t any `explicitly set` here, why it still works?

Comment: @pinopino dapper *always* explicitly sets the type; in your example, it is in the `...` - the actual line is `parameter.DbType = this.IsAnsi ? (this.IsFixedLength ? DbType.AnsiStringFixedLength : DbType.AnsiString) : (this.IsFixedLength ? DbType.StringFixedLength : DbType.String);`. We use `DbType` rather than `SqlDbType` because dapper is not tied to SQL-Server (it works on any ADO.NET provider) - but the result is the same; that conveys the same information.

Comment: sorry, in fact that was totally another question, i posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406202/mapping-of-net-framework-types-to-dbtype-the-weird-string-nvarchar-and-char). as for this one, thank you Marc, your explain do a great help on me!

Comment: Just to be clear, IsAnsi should be true for varchar, and false for nvarchar. IsFixed should be true for [n]char and false for [n]varchar.