# Dapper and varchars

Tags: varchar, dapper

I found the following comment on [the Dapper .NET project home page](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/).

> Dapper supports varchar params, if you are executing a where clause on a varchar column using a param be sure to pass it in this way:

```
    Query<Thing>("select * from Thing where Name = @Name", new {Name = 
    new DbString { Value = "abcde", IsFixedLength = true, Length = 10, IsAnsi = true });
```

> On Sql Server it is crucial to use the unicode when querying unicode and ansi when querying non unicode

I'm evaluating Dapper for use with a legacy database (SQL Server 2008), with lots of stored procedures with varchar parameters, and I'm a little confused by this restriction.

With hand-crafted ADO.NET code, I'd use the following for the above query:

```
new SqlParameter("@Name", "abcde")
```

without specifying whether it's unicode or not, nor the length.

- Why do I  need this verbose DbString syntax with Dapper, specifying the column length, IsFixedLength and IsAnsi?
- Why IsFixedLength = true for a varchar column (I'd expect it to be true for a char or nchar column)?
- Do I have to use DbString like this for stored procedure parameters?

I was expecting Dapper to make my DAL code more concise, but this seems to be making it more verbose for varchar parameters.

**UPDATE**

I've researched a bit further, to try to understand why Dapper would have this varchar restriction, which I don't appear to have in my hand-crafted code, where I would normally create an input parameter as follows:

```
var parameter = factory.CreateParameter(); // Factory is a DbProviderFactory
parameter.Name = ...;
parameter.Value = ...;
```

and usually leave the provider to infer the `DbType` using its own rules, unless I specifically want to coerce it.

Looking at Dapper's `DynamicParameters` class, it has a method `AddParameters` which creates parameters as follows:

```
var dbType = param.DbType; // Get dbType and value
var val = param.Value;     // from 

...
// Coerce dbType to a non-null value if val is not null !!!!!
if (dbType == null && val != null) dbType = SqlMapper.LookupDbType(val.GetType(),name);
...
var p = command.CreateParameter();
...
if (dbType != null)                     
{                         
    p.DbType = dbType.Value;                     
}
```

I.e. it explicitly coerces `IDataParameter.DbType` to a value it looks up with its own algorithm, rather than leaving the provider to use its own rules.

Is there a good reason for this?  It seems wrong for me, particularly in the light of the comment about Dapper's support for varchar parameters.

Comment: For the first questions (about strings), this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47772877/3606250

Answer (score 0):

You need this syntax when working with ODBC.

You would need to define a CHAR(30) field as a DbString in c# for Dapper and also set the length (30) and ansi (true) values to prevent Dapper from assuming the string was a text/blob type.  Otherwise you will likely receive the error:  "Illegal attempt to convert Text/Byte blob type".

I was getting this error using ODBC to connect to Informix until I defined my param as a DbString() and set the length and ansi values.

[More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416876/handler-mapping-of-string-to-varchar-in-dapper).

Answer (score -3):

```
var param = new { Varchar1 = "", Varchar2 = "" };
db.Query("SP", param, commandType:CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code only answers are not very useful on their own. It would help if you could add some detail explaining how/why it answers the question.

Comment: It is a bit unclear question, but should be a sufficient indication for others how to use varchars and stored procedures.