# DbString, IsFixedLength and IsAnsi for varchar

Tags: dapper

I am new to Dapper, want to know why below is suggested, when my code runs without it?

> [Ansi Strings and varchar](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper#ansi-strings-and-varchar)
>
> Dapper supports varchar params, if you are executing a where clause on
> a varchar column using a param be sure to pass it in this way:
>
> ```
>  Query<Thing>("select * from Thing where Name = @Name", new {Name = new
>  DbString { Value = "abcde", IsFixedLength = true, Length = 10, IsAnsi
>  = true });
> ```
>
> On SQL Server it is crucial to use the unicode when querying unicode
> and ansi when querying non unicode.

Below is my code, which runs against SQL server 2012 without using DbString etc.

```
create table Author (
 Id int identity(1,1),
 FirstName varchar(50),
 LastName varchar(50)
);
go
insert into Author (FirstName, LastName) values ('Tom', 'John');

        public Author FindByVarchar(string firstName)
        {
            using (IDbConnection db = DBHelper.NewSqlConnection())
            {
                return db.Query<Author>("Select * From Author WHERE FirstName = @firstName", new { firstName }).SingleOrDefault();
            }
        }
```

**Questions:**

1 Why is DbString type used in this case?

2 Why the length is set to 10 (e.g.Length = 10) when "abcde" is 5?

3 Do I still need to use DbString when my current code works?

4 Is it correct to set IsAnsi = false for unicode column?

5 For varchar column, is it correct to set IsFixedLength = false, and ignore setting Length?

Comment: I believe the reason DbString is recommended is that otherwise it would be an NVARCHAR parameter which would result in an index scan rather than an index seek, potentially impacting performance: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/07/18/troubleshooting-sql-index-performance-on-varchar-columns/  Though in this case I would consider using `WHERE FirstName = CAST(@firstName AS VARCHAR(n))` rather than the hassle of DbString.  I assume (but haven't tested) that this would result in an index seek.

Comment: BTW I asked a similar question some time ago, but never had a satisfactory response.  But thinking about it led me to the conclusion in the comment above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362113/dapper-and-varchars

Comment: If stored procedure is used which defines correct type of parameter (e.g. varchar/nvarchar), DbString is not needed. Is it correct?

Comment: yes, I'm pretty sure your correct.

Comment: I think stored procedure will be used in production. But I would like to know the reason if possible. Thanks @Joe

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The purpose of the example is that it is describing a scenario where the data type is `char(10)`. If we just used `"abcde"`, Dapper might think that `nvarchar(5)` was appropriate. This would be very inefficient in some cases - especially in a `where` clause, since the RDBMS can decide that it can't use the index, and instead needs to table scan doing a string conversion for every row in the table from `char(10)` to the `nvarchar` version. It is for this reason that `DbString` exists - to help you control *exactly* how Dapper configures the parameter for text data.

I think this answers your 1 and 2.

3: are you using ANSI (non-unicode text) or fixed-width text? Note that the ANSI default can also be set globally if you *always* avoid unicode

4: yes

5: yes

4+5 combined: if you're using `nvarchar`: *just use `string`*

Comment: On Q3, Does it mean it depends on the default settings of Query<T>? Is it correct that using DbString always explicitly specifies if it is fixed or variable,  and ansi or unicode,  What if stored procedure with parameter is used? so this issue does not exist? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @pingping if you are calling a sproc then even if they are wrong, the values should be converted once only - inside the sproc they'll be the right type, so you shouldn't see the same issues in that case. Outside of sprocs, yes: DbString would explicitly control ANSI vs Unicode and fixed vs variable length

Comment: It would be helpful if this was explained in more detail in the Dapper readme (https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/main/Readme.md).  As far as I can tell. this performance issue is not specific to Dapper, and an alternative solution would be to use a cast in the where clause (`... WHERE MyCol = CAST(@MyParameter AS NVARCHAR(5))...`.  This is a technique I've used with non-Dapper code where performance is an issue.