# How do I tell Dapper to use varchar for a list of params in a "WHERE" clause that uses "IN"?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dapper

I found this explanation and solution for using Dapper to search a `VARCHAR` field using a `string` as input:

```
Query<Thing>("select * from Thing where Name = @Name", new {Name = 
new DbString { Value = "abcde", IsFixedLength = true, Length = 10, IsAnsi = true });
```

Source: [Dapper and varchars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362113/dapper-and-varchars)

**But is there a way to adapt this to do the `DbString` conversion for every item in a list (using an IN clause)?**

The query I am trying to run looks like this:

```
Query<IndexRec>("SELECT * FROM T_INDEX WHERE CallId IN @callIds",
new { callIds = model.LogEntries.Select(x => x.Id) });
```

Unfortunately, this query runs slowly because:

1. `model.LogEntries` contains around 300 items.
2. T_INDEX.CallId is a `VARCHAR(30)` field.
3. As I understand, Dapper uses `NVarchar` with strings in a `WHERE` clause by default.
4. This causes an implicit conversion of every row in my table in SQL, which slows down the query significantly.

**How can I tell Dapper to use ansi strings in my `IN` clause for this query?**

Comment: How about `callIds = model.LogEntries.Select(x => new DbString { Value = x.Id, IsAnsi = true })`?

Comment: You should use join if both the tables are in the s same database

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: `LogEntries` is not a table at all. It's a list of items I get from an external source.

Comment: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/789

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to pass in a list of `DbString` items, for example:

```
var parameters = model.LogEntries
    .Select(x => new DbString 
    {
        Value = x.Id, 
        IsAnsi = true
    });

Query<IndexRec>("SELECT * FROM T_INDEX WHERE CallId IN @callIds", new { callIds = parameters })
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Works like a champ. Thanks.